# How to access SSL certificates stored in a DB from Apache CXF

Tags: java, rest, https, cxf

I have a Rest service implemented using **Apache CXF with HTTPS authentication**. Currently, the certificates are stored in keystore files.

Is there any way to get the certificate from a DB rather than from a file ?